# React - Override all previous clashing styles when adding a new class

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have seen a lot of threads on the topic, but nothing seems to work for me the way I want it. I have a React component which takes in className as a prop. I also have a HOC which takes in a component and default style, and returns a component which takes in a new style, as such:

```
function withCombinedStyles(WrappedComponent, defaultClassName) {
    return ({className: newClassName, ...rest}) => {
        const className = combineClassNames(newClassName, defaultClassName);

        return <WrappedComponent className={className} {...rest} />;
    };
};
```

Currently, combineClassNames just concatenates the strings. I want to make it so that the `newClassName` always overrides the clashing styles with the `defaultClassName` but keeps the old ones. Currently, one of the styles seems to override the other but without apparent order - it doesn't matter how I put `defaultClassName` and newClassName. How can I do that? Currently, I use CSS modules but the project is still small enough for me to be able to rewrite the styles with another technology if that would achieve the desired result and CSS modules cannot do that (though I would prefer to use CSS modules and a React-specific solution with them would work since).

I would use `!important` but that would mean that I can never add a third className and it could be challenging to extend the styling in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you were doing CSS in JS then the order would matter, but because you're just combining CSS class names what really matters is specificity. Say `newClassName` has declarations that are less specific than the ones in `defaultClassName` - then the more specific declarations in `defaultClassName` will win over. You can probably fix your CSS by just ensuring the statements you want to 'win' are more specific.

Check out calculators like [this one](https://polypane.app/css-specificity-calculator/)

If you went with inline CSS-in-JS styles I think something like this might work:

```js
function withCombinedStyles(WrappedComponent, defaultStyles) {
    return ({styles: newStyles, ...rest}) => {
        return <WrappedComponent style={{...defaultStyles, ...newStyles}} {...rest} />;
    };
};
```

Comment: That would work, but I don't know if the cost of css-in-js is worth it. I could do some things to work with the specificity (such as .logo.logo for example) but it is a pretty unclean way. Thanks for the suggestion!